# Custom design context menu on Electron

Tags: javascript, electron

I have my code for a context menu and work perfectly fine.

```
var menu = new Menu();
menu.append(new MenuItem({
    label: 'Delete', click() {
        clicked.remove()
        clicked.unbind()
    }
}));
menu.append(new MenuItem({
    label: 'Add', click() {
        alert("TBD")
    }
}));
```

But it appears with the default view of chromium. It's there a way to customize the design of the context-menu?

Comment: You mean like with css?

Comment: @Souleste Yes, but the context-menu it's over the electron app.

Comment: I found this :/ https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/4990

Comment: @Souleste thanks. I've searched and didn't find anything. I think I need to prevent the popup from the context-menu and create my own with CSS will be easier.